# Temporarily reverting back and forth in commits

Tags: git

I wanted to temporarily revert to a previous commit. So I did:

```
git checkout <commit_sha>
```

And how can I revert back? If I do "git log" I don't the most recent commit, instead I see only the current commit I've reverted to just now.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout <sha1>` switches to a detached HEAD, i.e. no actual branch, so you can switch back to the previous state with `git checkout <branch_name>`.

By the way, reverting in git is `git revert <sha1>`, which creates a revert commit.